How to hide or remove an attribute on condition from an input tag in AngularJS
We are using AngularJS (version 1). How can I remove/hide an attribute from an input tag using condition?
<input type="number" ng-class="{'ng-invalid' : function(param)}"  min="1" max="5" ng-model=value custom-attribute="" key="{{anotherFunction(param)}}">

Here, there is a function call with parameter that checks if the input number is invalid and give true if its invalid. There is another function for key thats custom made that will create a  yellow box. When its invalid, I dont have to show the yellow box. Even if null is there as value for key, that yellow box will come. So, I have to totally remove that attribute if its invalid. I have to totally remove key and custom-attribute when function(param) returns true. How to do this using angularJS
I have tried using ng-attr but have'nt got any luck.

Can you provide more info about the use case?
